# Types of light in computer graphics

Tags: graphics, light

Considering the two types of light in an illumination model, can I understand the *area light source* as the infinite number of point lights distributed over an area? Or is this number finite and the whole area is composed of physical objects like e.g. bulbs?

Comment: Where do these terms (area light source, etc. ) come from?

Comment: My lecture :) We distinguished between _point light sources_ and _area light sources_ and I'm just trying to get it in the right way, whether _area light source_ consists of finite or infinite point light sources, or maybe it doesn't have to do anything at all with it?

Comment: And what was the distinction? Cause as i understand them, they are the same thing.

Comment: In my lecture notes the professor wrote only: *_area light sources_ - distributed

Comment: Then ask the professor for definitions/sources

Comment: I would have already done it if I had such a possibility. I don't thus I'm asking here

Comment: We can only guess because we do not have access to the source material and do not know the intention of the author. A guess is not the type of answer that is encouraged on Stack Overflow

Comment: You *could* understand it as an infinite number of sources, but the contribution of those sources must be **infinitesimal** (otherwise the amount of light would also be infinite). Theoretically it is a uniform light distribution.